# Assigning player prefab based on playerIndex at runtime using Unity input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I want to have some prefabs already in the scene and then assign the players each one to control. The Input Manager is pretty clear for assigning prefabs when a player joins, but can this be changed later?

[image]

I know I can have a parent game object with several inactive prefabs as children and activate as needed, but this won't work with my current situation. Really need to just switch altogether if possible.

[image]

I'd like to use the "join manually" option which requires me to drag prefabs into the scene in the editor, then how do I assign players to them once the scene starts?

Something like:

```
if (GetComponent<PlayerInput>().playerIndex == 0)
        {
            
            "the player becomes prefab 1"

        }

if (GetComponent<PlayerInput>().playerIndex == 1)
        {
            
            "the player becomes prefab 2"

        }
```

I'm not sure how to access this by code (I'm pretty new) The input manager script appears uneditable, but before I realized this I tried adding some additional public game objects.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly your intend is to keep the players on scene while changing who controls them, right?

You should be able to get the player disconnected an reconnected to a new index without deleting the Player object from scene. Make shure you use methods properly using the docs: [Player Input Manager Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.2/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Plugins.PlayerInput.PlayerInputManager.html).

Otherwise I think you need an extra layer or some twist. Maybe keep the players on their indexes but change whos controlling the Player GameObjects?

By the way you can instantiate Prefabs by code using [Instantiate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

You can also use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance) to extend PlayerInputManager and maybe add some SwitchPlayer() function if really needed.

```
public class CustomPIM : PlayerInputManager {}
```

The custom class will inherit all methods from PlayerInputManager plus whatever you add.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe the answer has to do with inheritance, will have to look more into it. It just seems like it should be easier to change who's controlling what at any given time. I'd like to keep the players on their indexes but change/assign who's controlling which prefab at runtime.

Comment: I insist, you should be able to disconnect the PlayerInput and reconnect it within the same frame. Even if not, a couple frames of delay wont hurt since Human Players will need also some mental time to process the change.

Comment: Im kind of confused. How will disconnecting (and then reconnecting) them help?  How would you go about doing what you mentioned when you said this: "Maybe keep the players on their indexes but change whos controlling the Player GameObjects?"

Comment: To clarify, I'm going to call PlayerInput objects Controllers and Player Prefab objects Players. You have 4 Players on Scene. When Controllers join, you connect them to a Player. If you want to switch, disconnect the Controller (free the old Player) and reconnect it to the selected new Player.

I said that as another option. You can keep the Controllers static and make the logic on each Player. But I would recommend the first approach.